# Api-platform filter annotation for Many To Many

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

I've follow the implementation of filters with annotation to load only the sources concern for one user. Very usefull, work properly.

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#using-doctrine-filters

BUT : I want to do the same in my entity with an **ManyToMany** relationship and not ManyToOne like this :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiSubresource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use App\Annotation\UserAware;

/**
 *
 * @ApiResource(routePrefix="/api")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="albums")
 * @UserAware(userFieldName="user_owner")
 * @UserAware(userFieldName="album_access_user")
 */
class Album
{
    //...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, name="user_owner", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    public $userOwner;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="albums")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="album_access")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *  name="album_access",
     *  joinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="album_access_album", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  },
     *  inverseJoinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="album_access_user", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  }
     * )
    */
    private $accesses;

    //...
}
```

AS there is a JoinTable now and not just a JoinColum, i have to adapt the UserFilterConfigurator.php Event but i've no idea how to do that to give him the table and not juste the column...

Here is the logic error i get because i ask for the Entity Table and not the Join Table for now :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT DISTINCT o0_.id AS id_0, o0_.id AS id_1 FROM albums o0_ WHERE (o0_.album_access_user = '4') ORDER BY o0_.id ASC LIMIT 30':\n\nSQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column o0_.album_access_user does not exist\nLINE 1: ...id_0, o0_.id AS id_1 FROM albums o0_ WHERE (o0_...
```

**How can I get that for ManyToMany <=> how can i pass the good (join)table + (join) column ??**